# Xcode 4.4.1 Error Validating Mac app : CFBundleExecutable of two bundles may not point to the same file

Tags: xcode, macos, validation

I'm hitting this error after upgrading to Xcode 4.4.1 + 10.8.2.  (Both were done at the same time).  This is when validating an archive from an Xcode project for the mac app store.

The full error is :

> CFBundleexecutable of two bundles may not point to the same file.  The following shared bundle path have been found: MyAppName.app/Contents.

I'm not really sure what this means, the same exact source compiled without errors on 10.7.x Xcode 4.3.x.  However I need to compile on 10.8.x & XCode 4.4.x+.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

After trying a few things, I was able to fix it.  The issue here was the Info.plist file was included in the 'copy bundle resources' build phase.  Since this file is already copied by XCode elsewhere, it was causing the conflict.  I removed the Info.plist from the 'copy bundle resources' build phase, and that fixed the issue.

Due to the unclear message given by XCode, hopefully this will at least help others a bit more quickly in the future.

Comment: I had the same problem, and I can verify this fixes it.  Info.plist seems to be a 'special' file that automatically gets copied outside the `copy bundle resources` step, but the act of dragging it into the resources folder (if you're setting up an XCode file with an existing info.plist file; say, rebuilding a project) incorrectly adds it to that step.

Comment: You saved me so much time. Thanks! :-)

Comment: Actually the info.plist of an app should not be included in its Contents/Resources directory.

Comment: I had two  Info.plist files. Deleting redundunt/old one solved the issue. Thanks to Six Foot Three Foot :)

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!! It's 5 am, I've been working for 15 hours today on a final deadline to get our 1.0 submission in...and I hit this error which I'd never seen before. I would have given up for the night if I didn't find this. Thank you so much, from 4 years in the future :)

Comment: saved several hours of frustration  - thank you from the future

Comment: Thank you for this solution. In my case it was an info.plist from a framework that I recently added.

Comment: Ran into this with one project with two targets.  Adding the second info.plist file for the second target resulted it in being added to the resource import list.

Comment: stackoverflow to the rescue yet again!